# Microphone doesn't pick up sound on Asus Expertbook Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I got a new laptop (Asus Expertbook) and recently installed 22.04 on it. I'm getting the audio set up now, but running into trouble. I'm not able to record sound or use any input. It plays audio just fine, and several sound input devices appear in the listing, but none of them pick up sound. I saw another post had luck when upgrading to 23.04, so I did that, but no changes.

Alsamixer says PipeWire is at full volume. [image].

`pavucontrol` shows this for inputs:

[image]

One of these entries (the one ending with "Speaker + Headphones") shows activity based on audio output, rather than input. That seems weird to me but it could be normal.